# How to get BASH array length with descriptive/readable statement?

Tags: arrays, bash, count, code-readability

It seems like the standard way to get the length of an array in BASH is with `${#myArray[@]}`, like so:

```sh
myArray=( 1 3 5 7 9 )
length=${#myArray[@]}

echo "length: $length" # length: 5
```

That syntax is disgustingly cryptic and unreadable, though. Is there any built-in method similar to `count( $myArray )`, `myArray.length`, etc?

Comment: Wrong language if that's the kind of syntax you want. Keep in mind, bash needs to keep itself a superset of the 1991 POSIX sh standard, which was largely inspired by ksh88, which itself was inspired by 1970s Bourne. Backwards compatibility constraints don't allow the kind of ground-up syntax redesign you'd apparently like to see.

Comment: (BTW, note the guidance about "rants in disguise" at https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask; referring to things as "disgusting" is... maybe less even-handed than might be considered ideal).

Comment: This isn't a "rant in disguise", it's a question that I genuinely want an answer to, in order to avoid committing unreadable code in a script that I'm working on right now. I can remove the "disgusting" bit if you really think it's inappropriate, but I can't imagine anybody making a legitimate argument that that syntax is readable.

Comment: If you think it's *not* within what a majority of developers are (or at least used to be) willing to learn as part of doing the job, you're too young to remember when Perl was the hot new thing. :P

Comment: If you think it's within what a majority of developers are willing to put up with, you're too old to appreciate modern programming languages. :P

Comment: As the other commentors mentioned, if your goal is to write code that is easy for maintainers with general programming experience to reason with, it would be best to implement it in a more complete language than Bash.  Bash scripts that need to be maintained by a group should be reserved for situations where it would be impractical to install another runtime/interpretter, or build a statically linked program to accomplish the task.

Comment: @ctt, I wouldn't describe modern bash as *incomplete*, just... unwieldy, surprising, and haphazardly designed (largely on account of backwards-compatibility constraints building up over decades). The featureset recently (which is to say, post-4.0) adopted from ksh93 (associative arrays, indirect assignments, etc) goes a long ways towards completeness.

Comment: The syntax most certainly isn't clear, but after doing a little bit of bash scripting you very quickly remember and get used to it. Stuff like this is the least of my concerns when using bash. At least there's a way to do it without shooting myself in the foot, even if the syntax is ... less than ideal.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm a die hard shell fan, but I think that the language has a limited set of uses and requires an abnormal level of defensiveness; not against unusual inputs, but against less experienced maintainers. The productivity lost maintaining shell scripts as a group should be offset against the benefits of using languages with runtimes that are _ubiquitous enough_ and provide more predictable syntax, and facilities for unit testing (and thus demonstrating the use of) code.  Although we're die hard bash lovers, it's hard to build a team composed entirely of die hard bash lovers.

Comment: "can't imagine anybody making a legitimate argument that that syntax is readable" Well, a 2013 study titled "An Empirical Investigation into Programming Language Syntax" found that a language with keywords selected randomly from an ascii table (`:` for `if`, `\ ` for assignment, etc) was not significantly less readable than Java for novices unfamiliar with either

Comment: just bind `len` or the like to a snippet expansion and be done with it.  It looks like you use PHP so you're no stranger to ugly syntax

Comment: @IanDunn, ...by the way, there's no shortage of people who agree with you, and have tried to build "modern" non-POSIX-compliant languages for shell-like use from the ground up. A great many of them I have trouble respecting as suited-to-task (I'd argue that you need to actually get a nontrivial amount of experience working in language-X in order to build a good replacement for language-X; of course, once you have that experience, you could also just keep using X, if the only objection is initial learning curve), but some are decent (scsh, f/e, is one I can respect).

Comment: ...wait, *PHP*?! [*snerk*](https://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw this answer out as a lark. Please realize that `eval` is a security hole through which you can drive a truck bomb if the data isn't carefully monitored and/or cleaned. The eval was an overly flippant use of sarcasm I should have made more clear. (I thought the line about Java or Perl would make that clear, but I guess not, lol)

Here's a more sensible version, which you'll notice used Charles Duffy's solution *almost* exactly.

```
lengthOf() {
  local -n standin=$1   # standin is a *reference* to the name passed
  echo "${#standin[@]}"
}
```

This works the same as my original below, but consider the typical use - most of the time, you're just going to want to save the return, so the idiom would be

```
len=$( lengthOf someArray )
```

If that's the case, *Please* see Charles' solution, as it's much better for that, assigning the variable directly in the same call.

---

> #### Original answer

If you just want syntactic sugar you're going to have to wade into the weeds of the parts you *don't* like, and maybe generate some fairly ugly security concerns as well... but here's an option, for the fun of the exercise. Someone will surely offer refinements.

```
lengthOf() { eval "echo \${#$1[@]}"; }
```

Now if you have an array declared as `a=( a b c )` you can do this:

```
lengthOf a
```

and it will print `3`. Just don't expect it to give you the length of a *string* instead of an array....

Bash is all about context, though, so if a little syntactic effort bothers you, maybe you should try another language... like Java, or Perl, lol! ;)

Comment: I don't think that Java or Perl are practical or compelling alternatives to Bash, but [Fish](https://fishshell.com) looks it's a lot more modern and sane, so I'm going to look into that for the future.

Comment: fish is very much in the languages-I-can't-respect-as-suited-to-task category. One of my company's founders wrote their scripts in fish, and they ended up needing to be *re*written almost without exception. It's a reasonable *interactive* shell, but the design parameters for an interactive shell and a scripting language aren't one and the same. (Indeed, a good interactive shell being a bad scripting language is why there are so many -- universally buggy -- csh scripts floating around).

Comment: ...POSIX sh is a mess, but at least it *is* a specification. Any language with an ad-hoc parser rather than a formal spec doesn't even have a well-defined concept of what "correct behavior" is, other than "whatever the reference implementation happens to do".

Comment: @PaulHodges, ...and *seriously*, `eval`? That's not just "maybe" on the security concerns, unless you add validation that the code is only invoked when `$1` is a valid variable name.

Comment: It was seriously just a POC as an exercise, lol. I generally hate `eval` as a thing, but it was a quick one-liner. Mea Culpa. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily *implement* `count "${myArray[@]}"`, if that would make you feel better:

```
count() { echo "$#"; }
length=$(count "${myArray[@]}")
```

...or, as an alternative that doesn't require a command substitution (and the attendant performance hit) to assign the result:

```
assignCount() {
  local -n assignCount_arr=$2
  printf -v "$1" %s "${#assignCount_arr[@]}"
}
assignCount length myArray
```

However, this doesn't exactly make the syntax easy and clean -- if it were misused by leaving out the quotes, f/e, arrays with contents that could be interpreted as glob expressions or whose contents contain characters in IFS could return incorrect values.

Frankly, bash isn't an easy-to-use language, and trying to treat it as if it were [leads to numerous, severe bugs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls). It's much more sensible to have the "here there be dragons" visible up-front than to let folks get complacent and leave major bugs in place by virtue of *not* learning the ins and outs of the execution model and syntax.

Comment: I would definitely not use these. They're very easy to misuse, and you end up having to use `"${a[@]}"` to use them properly, which is just as cryptic as `"${#a[@]}"` IMHO.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso, I agree; that said, one favorable argument about `"${a[@]}"` is that [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net/) will flag when it's required but not used.

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso The second one works without having to write `"${a[@]}"`. However, I would alter it so that it just prints the count instead of assigning it to a variable. That way you could use it as `echo "array has length $(length arrayName)"`.

Comment: @Socowi, sure, but that requires a `fork()` to use; it's not cheap performance-wise. Honestly, it's going to be faster to run `length arrayName arrayLen; echo "array has length $arrayLen"`.

Comment: @Charles Duffy fair point, but is `count "${a[@]}"` really that much better to read than `"${#a[@]}"`?

Comment: @CoffeeTableEspresso, well, sure; I think the OP's whole question is silly to begin with, but part of showing what a "better" syntax would look like within existing language constraints is to illustrate that. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I completely agree. It amounts to "I don't like the syntax of this language, is there a syntax that looks more like what I'm used to?". Not that bash has good syntax, but worrying about the syntax for getting array length seems a bit silly when you consider all the ways you can _actually_ shoot yourself in the foot with bash.